# FFMPEG for Android encode video from images get bad quality (not clear)

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I want to create video from image with ffmpeg in android platform. I have succeeded created it, but when i opened it the quality for video is bad. Anyone knows what I should do? Can Ffmpeg for android can create clear video ?

Thanks.

This is my reference :

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
- [androidwarzone.blogspot.co.id](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.id)

And command for create video like this, just put an example that i try :

```
ffmpeg -r 24 -i /storage/emulated/0/Zzz/pic%03d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf fps=24 -pix_fmt yuv420p /storage/emulated/0/Zzz_res/out.mp4

ffmpeg -y -r 24 -i /storage/emulated/0/Zzz/pic%03d.jpg -i /storage/emulated/0/Zzz_mus/music.mp3 -aspect 1:1 -ar 22050 -ac 1 -b 700k -ab 44100 /storage/emulated/0/Zzz_res/video_out.mp4
```

I have tried several combination, but the result is same, get bad quality. Anybody can help me?

FYI: There is no problem when i try Ffmpeg for desktop (video very clear and same with original video), but for Android i cant understand why getting bad quality.

Answer (score 0):

If i recall you'll need -q:v 1 or -q:v 0 to get high quality JPEGs

look into the 'image2' filter thingy in the docs.

Comment: The question is about making a video from JPEG images, not about outputting JPEG images. Also, `-q:v` will be ignored when encoding libx264. When encoding to JPEG, `-q:v 2` is the effective lowest value anyway (give it a try with the hash demuxer to see), unless you add `-qmin`.

Comment: I am getting   Missing argument for option '-q:v 1'.